# What happens in circuits where the propagation time of the electric field is significant?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electricity, electric-circuits

Kirchhoff's current law assumes "*[that whenever current flows into one end of a conductor it immediately flows out the other end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Limitations)*".

I want to understand what happens when we cannot make this assumption.

In the circuit below, imagine that $S1$ has been open (disconnected) for a long time. At a time $t = 0$ the switch is instantaneously closed. If we assume that the LEDs have instantaneous switching time, at what time $t$ will $D1$ and $D2$ emit light?

Do the LEDs begin to emit light simultaneously? Do they emit light after 3 light-seconds, 1.5 light-seconds, or some other time?

My guess is that $D1$ will emit light at $t = 1s$ and $D2$ will emit at $t = 3s$. It should be impossible for $D1$ to emit light when $t < 1s$ and for $D2$ to emit light when $t < 3s$. If this were not the case then this would result in superluminal communication, which violates causality.

[image: Circuit with a single switch in series with two LEDs]

What happens when a second switch $S2$ is introduced to the circuit below? Imagine that both switches have been open for a long time. At time $t=0$ both $S1$ and $S2$ are simultaneously closed.

At what time $t$ do the LEDs emit light? What changes compared to first circuit?

[image: Circuit with two switches that open and close simultaneously]

Assumptions:

- The LEDs and switches are placed in close proximity to each other, although the length of the wires separating them may be very long. For example, $S1$ and $D1$ are separated by a 1 light-second length of wire, however, we assume that they are physically placed close together relative to a human observer looking at the circuit. Only the electrical paths have significant propagation times.
- The electric field propagates through the circuit at ***c***
- All circuit elements are ideal
- Switches and LEDs have instantaneous switching time
- When a switch is open, it is physically disconnected from the circuit.
- There are no parasitic resistances, capacitances, or inductances

Comment: @brucesmitherson Because if the answer is the same then it would violate causality. It takes 1s for the information from S1 to reach D1, and 2s for the information from S2 to reach D1. Thus, D1 could not turn at t=1s in both cases.

Comment: Assuming there's no parasitic inductance or capacitance makes this question un-answerable.

Comment: @DanielSank Could you please explain why that would make this question unanswerable?

Comment: The propagation of electromagnetic waves depends fundamentally on the same thing that causes parasitic capacitance and inductance. When you put a high frequency electrical signal on a wire, you get wave-like transmission, and that wave motion depends exactly on the inductance and capacitance per length of the wire. Energizer777's answer links to a Wikipedia article all about this.

Comment: @DanielSank If what you are saying is true, the Telegrapher's equations would be invalid for steady state DC current, where the series inductances and parallel capacitances contribute nothing to the transmission. However, we know that the Telegrapher's equations remain valid when the series inductances and parallel capacitances are set to zero. If L=C=0 you would not realistically model a practical transmission line that **does** have parasitic elements. Fortunately, my original question is a thought experiment and not a practical system.

Comment: Essentially you're asking "What if there is an electric current that does not create a magnetic field (with its concomitant energy)".

Comment: What you need to do is find a good book on transmission line theory. At the time scales you're talking about, distributed capacitances and inductances become important. What happens after you close the switch is that a voltage and current pulse are sent through the wire and there is a lot of ringing and reflections of pulses back and forth until a steady-state situation equivalent to a conventional DC analysis solution of the circuit is reached.

Answer (score 3):

Any wire circuit will have inductance and capacitance between the "outbound" and "return" wires - this immediately follows from very basic laws of physics, and in fact is intimately related to the finite propagation velocity of the electrical signal.  The expression

$$u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$$

would give an infinite velocity if either $L$ or $C$ was zero... So I am not going to answer the non-physical question "in the absence of parasitic inductance and capacitance".

This relationship is usually explained in terms of the [Telegrapher's Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations), which show that a transmission line will have a characteristic impedance, and that a signal travels along such transmission line with a velocity related to the speed of light in the medium between the conductors. If the conductors are in vacuum, the speed of propagation is the speed of light.

We cannot answer your question and ignore this. But if we do take it into account, we can analyze the voltage pulse that travels along the wire - and the current that it generates.

We need to know the characteristic impedance of the wire. Again, the Telegrapher's Equations come to our help, and we find that

$$Z = \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}$$

Thus, if we apply a voltage $V$ at the start of the transmission line, there will be a current $I = \frac{V}{Z+R}$ that starts to flow into the circuit immediately. An LED that is close to the voltage source will light *to the extent that this current is sufficient to light it*. Note that $Z+R$ is always greater than $R$, so the current is initially less than the steady state current.

Once the voltage pulse reaches the far end of the circuit, it will be reflected by the "short circuit" that is present there; and this results in the circuit finally "knowing" it is part of a circuit. The reflected pulse (inverted voltage) will take another second to travel back.

The presence of the LEDs with their finite impedance makes the calculation of the actual intensity of the emissions quite complex, as they result in partial reflections: consequently there will be multiple reflections back and forth before the steady state is reached. But the bottom line is:

1. D2 will light 1 second before D1
2. The answer is unchanged when you introduce the second switch
3. In either case, the final intensity is not reached until several seconds after closing the switch(es)

Comment: Wouldn't it take at least 1.5 light seconds longer for D1 to turn on when the second switch is introduced?

Answer (score 0):

> What happens in circuits where the propagation time of the electric field is significant?

The answer to your question is given in the article: [Telegrapher's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations).

*"The telegrapher's equations (or just telegraph equations) are a pair of coupled, linear differential equations that describe the voltage and current on an electrical transmission line with distance and time. The equations come from Oliver Heaviside who in the 1880s developed the transmission line model, which is described in this article. The model demonstrates that the electromagnetic waves can be reflected on the wire, and that wave patterns can appear along the line. The theory applies to transmission lines of all frequencies including high-frequency transmission lines (such as telegraph wires and radio frequency conductors), audio frequency (such as telephone lines), low frequency (such as power lines) and direct current."*, [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations).

Comment: The telegrapher's equations are definitely the right place to start. Can you give more of an answer on how to use them to predict the behavior of the circuit? As written this post doesn't answer the question.